# When I use Beautiful Soup library find_all it finds only half of what I ask

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```py
URL_ZILLOW = "https://www.zillow.com/manhattan-new-york-ny/rentals/1-1_beds/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22Manhattan%2C%20New%20York%2C%20NY%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-74.08612384255531%2C%22east%22%3A-73.66315020974281%2C%22south%22%3A40.65707407862896%2C%22north%22%3A40.911828962172066%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A12530%2C%22regionType%22%3A17%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A472874%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22max%22%3A1700%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%2C%22max%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A11%7D "



response = requests.get(URL_ZILLOW, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
prices = [price.getText() for price in self.soup.find_all("div", "list-card-price")]
addresses = [address.getText() for address in self.soup.find_all(name="address", class_="list-card-addr")]
links = [link['href'] for link in self.soup.find_all(name="a", class_="list-card-link")]
```

Comment: Don't make us guess, nor should it be necessary to run your provided code to make sense of your question: I suggest adding details of what results you're currently getting and what results you expect, and perhaps a bit of explanation of what you're expecting back from the URL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are needlessly scraping HTML when there is a backend api that can be hit, open your browsers Developer Tools - Network - fetch/XHR and then refresh the page. You'll see a network request to their backend api, you can copy it into a new tab in your browser and see the json data, very easy to scrape:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

paste_network_tab_page_2_url = 'https://www.zillow.com/search/GetSearchPageState.htm?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22Philadelphia%2C%20PA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-75.62199789164843%2C%22east%22%3A-74.70875936625781%2C%22south%22%3A39.528020026936595%2C%22north%22%3A40.41625050351642%7D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sortSelection%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%2C%22isAllHomes%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D&wants={%22cat1%22:[%22listResults%22,%22mapResults%22],%22cat2%22:[%22total%22]}&requestId=11'

headers =   {
    'accept':'application/json',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36'
    }

final = []
for page in range(1,5): #edit for page numbers, you might get banned if you go wild

    print(f'Scraping page: {page}')

    url = paste_network_tab_page_2_url.replace('currentPage%22%',f'currentPage%2{page}%')

    resp = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
    for result in resp['cat1']['searchResults']['listResults']:

        detected = resp['user']['isBot']
        _id = result['id']
        url = result['detailUrl']
        img = result['imgSrc']
        _type = result['statusType']
        price = result['unformattedPrice']
        address = result['address']
        try:
            _zip = result['addressZipcode']
        except KeyError:
            _zip = ''

        try:
            beds = result['beds']
        except KeyError:
            beds = ''

        try:
            baths = result['baths']
        except KeyError:
            baths = ''

        try:
            lat = result['latLong']['latitude']
            lng = result['latLong']['longitude']
        except KeyError:
            lat = ''
            lng = ''

        try:
            age = result['variableData']['text']
        except KeyError:
            age =''

        try:
            area = result['area']
        except:
            area = ''

        item  = {
            'detected?lol' : detected,
            'id' : _id,
            'url' : url,
            'img' : img,
            'type' : _type,
            'price' : price,
            'address' : address,
            'zip' : _zip,
            'beds' : beds,
            'baths' : baths,
            'lat' : lat,
            'lng' : lng,
            'age' : age,
            'area' : area
        } #lots more data than this in the file, go have a look at the contents of 'print(resp['cat1']['searchResults']['listResults'])'

        final.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(final)

df.to_csv('zillow_results.csv',index=False)
print('results saved in file: zillow_results.csv')
```